# How to refer to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, registry, windows-11, powershell-7.2

```
New-Item -Path "HKCR:\Directory\Background\shell\customname" -Force
```

I've been doing the same thing for HKCU and KHLM but when I try HKCR I get errors in PowerShell. how am I supposed to do it for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT?

I searched for a solution but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a *custom drive* whose root is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, as shown [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74337077/45375), is definitely an option, especially for repeated use.

Ad hoc, you can **alternatively use the `Registry::` [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) prefix** directly **with *native* registry paths**:

```bash
New-Item -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\customname' -Force
```

Note:

- The `Registry` part of the prefix is the *provider name*, as shown in [`Get-PSProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psprovider)'s output.
- Hypothetically, *multiple* providers with the same name could be registered, in which case you can prefix the name with the implementing *module* name for disambiguation; in the case of the registry provider, this module-qualified prefix is `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::`<sup>[1]</sup> However, it's fair to assume that no third-party providers will choose a name that conflicts with the providers that ship with PowerShell, so `Registry::` (or `registry::`, case doesn't matter), should do.

  - Note that the module-qualified provider name does show up in the prefix of the `.PSPath` property that provider items, such as reported by [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) and [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), are decorated with, e.g.:

    ```bash
    PS> (Get-Item HKCU:\Console).PSPath

    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
    ```

---

<sup>[1] Note that the `Core` part of the name does *not* refer to the PowerShell (Core) *edition*; it simply denotes a module that is at the core of either edition.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Okay I figured out on my own,

checked `Get-PSDrive`

and saw the only registry aliases available by default on Windows/PowerShell are

```
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

so, what I did, [following this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.2), was to add a new alias for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` that is called `HKCR`

```
New-PSDrive -Name "HKCR" -PSProvider Registry -Root "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"
```